# Division in html is causing all content below to disapear

Tags: html

So I have been able to mess around with the code and found that if I delete the division that separates the header section the rest of the code reappears. But I am not allowed to delete any divisions or else you fail the assignment.
[html code blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RlTx.png)

Comment: Hey there, you should post your code here in order for us to help you out. Also, a screenshot of the problem is a plus.

Comment: You should rather link your js file inside the head section or below, before the closing body tag. Whatever you are trying to pull out of the JS file put it inside a function and call the function name where you are linking tho the JS file. Looks like a dynamic name.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to this.

```
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main_css.css">
       <script src="javascript/external.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, Welcome to my website</h1>
        ... rest of your code ...
   </body>
```

Move the script into < head > section

Or at the end of the body. Otherwise the script is executed too early before the DOM is ready.

Comment: <script> tag can be anywhere - it's not limited to the <head>. The location isn't what's causing the problem.

Comment: Sure, it's just messy code though.. As developers on here we should always recommend best practice.. Especially to new students.

Comment: If that doesn't solve the issue, then it shouldn't be an answer. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯